# How to implement a node with multiple inbound and multiple outbound relations in graph

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

This is more a general question about graph database design, and I couldn't find a better title for my question.

I have Producer A and Producer B, who both produce apples. I buy these apples from them, but from A only 10,000 and from B 20,000.
How to draw this in a graph database, if I would like to have the amount of apples that I buy as a node (not as a relation attribute)?

As far as I can imagine it, I'd have two nodes of type "Producer", one node of type "Good", and two nodes of type "Buying Amount". Additionally there are two types of relations: "produces" and "needs_to_be_produced". (I am not sure if the relation titles are fiiting).

Here is a drawing: http://img198.imageshack.us/img198/3964/4klk.png

**The problem here is: Where do I know from if Producer A or B needs to produce 10,000 apples for me?**

I am open for any proposals and changes, but I would like to keep the amount of produced apples as a node.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to model in a layman terms.

Comment: For this example: I want to have a database storing information from whom I am purchasing which objects at which amount (and additionally also: at which point of time, e.g. "10,000 apples in August 2014").

Comment: Check my answer and comment if you have any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is how I've modeled. I've setup the [test data and sample query for you here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/b3hsvw).

**What quantity of a particular goods have been purchased from various producers**

```
MATCH t:Transaction-[:FOR]->g:Goods, t-[:FROM]->producer WHERE g.type='Apples' RETURN producer, t.quantity, t.month+"-"+t.year AS Date
```

**Output**

[image]

**Design**

**Nodes:** Goods (type), Transaction (quantity, date(month, year)), Producer (name)

**Relationships:** A *Transaction* is FOR a particular *Goods* and indicates that the purchase was FROM a particular *Producer*

**Setup**

```
CREATE (producerA:Producer {name:'A'})
CREATE (producerB:Producer {name:'B'})
CREATE (apples:Goods {type:'Apples'})
CREATE producerA-[:PRODUCES]->apples
CREATE producerB-[:PRODUCES]->apples
CREATE (trans1:Transaction {month:'08', year:'2014', quantity:'10000'})-[:FOR]->apples
CREATE trans1-[:FROM]->producerA
CREATE (trans2:Transaction {month:'08', year:'2014', quantity:'20000'})-[:FOR]->apples
CREATE trans2-[:FROM]->producerB
```

Answer (score 0):

I would introduce another node type, let's call it "purchase" (although I'm not sure what the best name is, would need more details about your use case).

```
(Producer A)-[:PRODUCES]->(Purchase X)
(Producer B)-[:PRODUCES]->(Purchase Y)
(Purchase X)-[:IS_FOR_PRODUCT]->(Apple)
(Purchase Y)-[:IS_FOR_PRODUCT]->(Apple)
(Purchase X)-[:IS_FOR_AMOUNT]->(10,000)
(Purchase Y)-[:IS_FOR_AMOUNT]->(20,000)
```

I hope the syntax is clear, () are nodes and -[:]-> are named directed relationships, like in Cypher.